# Is there any way to make Search and addToSearch faster?

Tags: c#, performance

Is there any way to make Search and addToSearch faster?
I am trying to make it faster. I am not sure if regex in addtosearch can be a problem, it is really small. I am out ofideas how to optimize it further. Now i am just trying to meet word count. I wonder if there is a way to concatenate parts of name that are not empty more effectivly than i do.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System;

namespace AutoComplete
{
    public struct FullName
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Surname;
        public string Patronymic;
    }

    public class AutoCompleter
    {
        private List<string> listOfNames = new List<string>();
        private static readonly Regex sWhitespace = new Regex(@"\s+");
        public void AddToSearch(List<FullName> fullNames)
        {
            foreach (FullName i in fullNames)
            {
                string nameToAdd = "";
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i.Surname))
                {
                    nameToAdd += sWhitespace.Replace(i.Surname, "") + " ";
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i.Name))
                {
                    nameToAdd += sWhitespace.Replace(i.Name, "") + " ";
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i.Patronymic))
                {
                    nameToAdd += sWhitespace.Replace(i.Patronymic, "") + " ";
                }
                listOfNames.Add(nameToAdd.Substring(0, nameToAdd.Length - 1));
            }
        }

        public List<string> Search(string prefix)
        {
            if (prefix.Length > 100 || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(prefix))
            {
                throw new System.Exception();
            }
            List<string> namesWithPrefix = new List<string>();
            foreach (string name in listOfNames)
            {
                if (IsPrefix(prefix, name))
                {
                    namesWithPrefix.Add(name);
                }
            }
            return namesWithPrefix;
        }
        private bool IsPrefix(string prefix, string stringToSearch)
        {
            if (stringToSearch.Length < prefix.Length)
            {
                return false;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < prefix.Length; i++)
            {
                if (prefix[i] != stringToSearch[i])
                {
                    return false
                }
            }
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: String concatenations are slow - the heap, cache and garbage collector are all in pain. Regex is slow. Searching unsorted lists is *incredibly* slow. RegEx is SLOW; it's used for flexibility, not for performance.

Comment: And https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expression (Regexp) are great because of their ease-of use and flexibility but **most Regexp engines are actually quite slow**. This is the case for the one of C#.  Moreover, strings can contain Unicode character and "\s" needs to consider all the (fancy) spaces characters included in the Unicode character set. This make Regexp search/replace much slower. If you know your input does not contain such characters (eg. ASCII), then you can write a much faster implementation. Alternatively, you can play with [`RegexpOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=net-6.0) like `Compiled` and `CultureInvariant` so to reduce a bit the run time.

The `AddToSearch` performs **many hidden allocations**. Indeed, `+=` create a new string (because C# string are *immutable* and not designed to be often resized) and `Replace` calls does allocate new strings too. You can speed up the computation by directly replace and write the result in a preallocated buffer and simply copy the result with a `Substring` like you currently do.

`Search` is fine and it is not easy to optimize it. That being said, if `listOfNames` is big, then you can use multiple threads so to significantly speed up the computation. Be careful though because `Add` is not thread-safe. [Parallel linkq](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelized-map-and-filter-operations/) may help you to do that easily (I never tested it though).

Another solution to speed up a bit the computation of `Search` is to start the loop of `IsPrefix` from `prefix.Length-1`. Indeed, if most string contains the beginning of the prefix, then a significant portion of the time will be spend comparing nearly equal characters. The probability that `prefix[prefix.Length-1] != stringToSearch[prefix.Length-1]` is higher than `prefix[0] != stringToSearch[0]`. Additionally, partial *loop unrolling* may help a bit to speed up the function if the JIT is not able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already pointed out that the use of regex can be problematic. I would personally consider using  str.Replace(" ", String.Empty) - if I understood the regex correctly; I normally try to avoid regex as I have a hard time reading code using regex. Note that String.Empty does not allocate a new string.

That said, I think performance could boost if you would not store the names in a List but at least order the list alpabetically. Thus you do not need to iterate all elemnts of the list but e.g. use binary search to find all elements matching a given prefix - as range within the list of names you already have.